# How to know if a sound card is capture only, playback only or capture and playback

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

Is there a command line i can apply to know if a sound card is capture only, playback only or "capture and playback" ?

I have found pacmd with this following pulseaudio command line:

```
pacmd list-cards
```

But i'm a bit confusing because my "jack mono to USB" card has inputs and outputs ...

Here is the output for this sound card generated by pacmd:

```
 index: 1
    name: <alsa_card.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Audio_Device-00>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "C-Media USB Audio Device"
        alsa.long_card_name = "C-Media USB Audio Device at usb-0000:00:14.0-8, full speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:8:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/sound/card0"
        udev.id = "usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Audio_Device-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "0d8c"
        device.vendor.name = "C-Media Electronics, Inc."
        device.product.id = "0008"
        device.product.name = "C-Media USB Audio Device   "
        device.serial = "0d8c_C-Media_USB_Audio_Device"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "C-Media USB Audio Device   "
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    profiles:
        input:mono-fallback: Entrée Mono (priority 1, available: unknown)
        input:multichannel-input: Entrée Multicanal (priority 1, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Sortie Stéréo analogique (priority 6500, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:mono-fallback: Sortie Stéréo analogique + Entrée Mono (priority 6501, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:multichannel-input: Sortie Stéréo analogique + Entrée Multicanal (priority 6501, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo: Sortie Stéréo numérique (IEC958) (priority 5500, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:mono-fallback: Sortie Stéréo numérique (IEC958) + Entrée Mono (priority 5501, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:multichannel-input: Sortie Stéréo numérique (IEC958) + Entrée Multicanal (priority 5501, available: unknown)
        off: Éteint (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:mono-fallback>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Audio_Device-00.analog-stereo/#1: C-Media USB Audio Device    Stéréo analogique
    sources:
        alsa_output.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Audio_Device-00.analog-stereo.monitor/#2: Monitor of C-Media USB Audio Device    Stéréo analogique
        alsa_input.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Audio_Device-00.mono-fallback/#3: C-Media USB Audio Device    Mono
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        multichannel-input: Entrée multicanal (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

        analog-output: Sortie analogique (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

        iec958-stereo-output: Sortie numérique (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
```

```
pacmd list-cards | grep -v -i -E "unknown|available: no" \
    | grep -i -E "alsa.card_name|alsa.card = |output|input"
```

```
    alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "USB Audio CODEC"
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
        alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo/#0: PCM2902 Audio Codec Stéréo analogique
        alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo.monitor/#0: Monitor of PCM2902 Audio Codec Stéréo analogique
        alsa_input.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo/#1: PCM2902 Audio Codec Stéréo analogique
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "C-Media USB Audio Device"
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:mono-fallback>
        alsa_output.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Audio_Device-00.analog-stereo/#1: C-Media USB Audio Device    Stéréo analogique
        alsa_output.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Audio_Device-00.analog-stereo.monitor/#2: Monitor of C-Media USB Audio Device    Stéréo analogique
        alsa_input.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Audio_Device-00.mono-fallback/#3: C-Media USB Audio Device    Mono
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo/#2: Audio interne Stéréo analogique
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor/#4: Monitor of Audio interne Stéréo analogique
        alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo/#5: Audio interne Stéréo analogique
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-output-headphones: Casque audio (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
        alsa.card = "3"
        alsa.card_name = "HX Stomp"
    active profile: <output:analog-surround-71+input:multichannel-input>
        alsa_output.usb-LINE_6_HX_Stomp_3013138-01.analog-surround-71/#3: HX Stomp Analog Surround 7.1
        alsa_output.usb-LINE_6_HX_Stomp_3013138-01.analog-surround-71.monitor/#6: Monitor of HX Stomp Analog Surround 7.1
        alsa_input.usb-LINE_6_HX_Stomp_3013138-01.multichannel-input/#7: HX Stomp Multicanal
```

Comment: It has both sinks and sources.

Comment: The log describes a jack to USB sound card with no headphone or speakers ouputs. So it is capture only and it has sources and sinks from pacmd point of view.

Comment: That USB device tells the computer that is has both an input and an output.

Comment: Yes, i know and this is annoying ... I don't understand why ! It is a capture only sound card. When i use it with jack, i have to plugin my headphone to another sound card in order to listen the input of this usb device.

Comment: That C-Media chip does not allow disabling a stream in its USB interface.

Comment: @CL, what does that mean "disable a stream in its USB interface" : how can i check that with a command line ?

Comment: You already did the check. Any such configuration would be done in hardware.